# Wordpress shortcode popup includes frontend

Tags: wordpress, redirect, popup, frontend, shortcode

I got a theme which has an registerred shortcode button for the editor mode.
When you click it opens a popup with the different options/shortcodes (popup.php).

In general this works fine but it happend that on some domains the popup doesn't show the shortcode options but it show the frontend of my theme/site.

Hope that someone has faced a similar issue to help, because I really don't know how i could solve this problem.
Maybe a redirecting problem of the domain???

**Code to open the popup by clicking the button.**

```
(function() {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.popup', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
        // Register commands
        ed.addCommand('mcepopup', function() {
            ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url + '/popup.php', // file that contains HTML for our modal window
                width : 700 + parseInt(ed.getLang('button.delta_width', 0)), // size of our window
                height : 700 + parseInt(ed.getLang('button.delta_height', 0)), // size of our window
                inline : 1
            }, {
                plugin_url : url
            });
        });

        // Register buttons
        ed.addButton('popup', {title : 'Insert Columns', cmd : 'mcepopup', image: url + '/images/button.png' });
    }

});

// Register plugin
// first parameter is the button ID and must match ID elsewhere
// second parameter must match the first parameter of the tinymce.create() function above
tinymce.PluginManager.add('popup', tinymce.plugins.popup);
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason why the popup would show the main page of theme/site is because the URL that has been requested is not valid.

From the code I understand that the URL of popup is derived by concatenating variable url and "/popup.php" - to verify if the URL is valid or not, try to copy the derived URL in the browser directly. If the main page of theme/site opens up then most probably the URL is not correct - most of the modern day site frameworks would redirect the user on main page for URLs that are non existing. In the backend you might be getting HTTP 404. If the generate URL of popup is not valid then verify the variable url and correct the same.

Another reason might be that popup.php page is generating some error (HTTP 500 server side error) and your site is configured to redirect user to home page on HTTP 500. This might be caused if the popup.php dependency is not configured properly.

Please verify your log files and check for any error message